# Regex 1964 to 2007

Tags: regex

In PHP, I know that `/^((19|20)\d\d)$/` will match all numbers from 1900 to 2099.

What is the most elegant way to match all numbers from 1964 to 2007 ?

`/^(196[456789]|19[789]\d|200[01234567])$/` ?

---

Edit:

Many answers to similar questions recommend using comparison instead of regex, for example because the regex is hard to read and difficult to maintain.

The problem with comparisons is that strings that are not numbers might match. For example:

```
$num = "";
if($num >= 0 && $num < 10) echo "yes";  // yes
```

Obviously an empty string is not a number between 0 and 10. So an easily maintainable comparison needs to check for numericity as well, which might make it less superior to a regex.

Comment: Elegant ? The usual solution is to not use a regex for that. The code you make is hard to read, to test, and if you need to change the numbers it can ends being very long.

Comment: `if ($num >= 1964 && $num < 2007) ` ?

Comment: @xdazz Aren't there other strings that will validate? Let's asume I'm validating 0 to 10, won't `$num = "";` validate (as zero) with your code?

Answer (score 1):

I would say `/^19(6[4-9]|[7-9]\d)|200[0-7]$/` is the most elegant way.

Comment: you need to limit the *count* of digits..`{2}`!

Comment: @NoobEditor Why? Which non-four-digit number will match?

Answer (score 0):

^(196[456789])|(197[0-9])|(198[0-9])|(199[0-9])|(200[0-7])$